# DBGrid and FieldName for new query field

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-7, dbgrid

I have DBGrid, but not all fields I can see inside Grid (TdxDBGrid)
[image]
Was adding three new fields(red V) to qPassengers and I don't see those values.
Here is part of query for DBGrid

```
SELECT * from  Workers left outer join Map on Workers.id = Map.WId
Workers.DecodedStreet AS Street,  
Workers.DecodedHouseNumber  AS StreetNum, 
Workers.DecodedCity AS City,
ISNULL(Map.DecodedStreet,'') AS DStreet,  // new field
ISNULL(Map.DecodedStreetNum,'') AS DStreetNum,  // new field
ISNULL(Map.DecodedCity,'') AS DCity  // new field
```

and after that with property SummaryGroups I placed new fields to my Grid,
BUT  I didn't find any New fields in property FieldName, that connecting fields from query with column in DBGrid

[image]

For example So I can't find corresponding field in FieldName for column dbGridTableDStreet,
because DStreet absent in FieldName list, BUT present in the query qPassengers

*Compile and Build was done *

Comment: If you have persistent fields defined in the query component then you need to add the new ones as well. Right click it and select fields editor then add the new fields.

Comment: I added new column (right side with V near DStreet ),
but I can't connect field from query to column . 
because don't see it (new field DStreet) in part of FieldName (in picture with red sign question ) . 
                                                      
Where add those new field ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grid is using data taken from 'qPassengers' dataset. If this dataset is using persistent fields, then adding the fields to the query of the dataset is not enough to make them visible. The new fields must first be added to the persistent fields collection of the 'qPassengers' dataset. Click with your right mouse button on the 'qPassengers' dataset and open the fields editor to do so.